# get file of shortcode wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with wordpress and want to change the output of a shortcode that I wrote myself earlier. Because I forgot where I put it (bad organizing when I started with wp) I wondered whether there is a list of all shortcodes with their source files in the wp database somewhere? 

Is there a list that wp uses to connect a shortcode it finds on the page to the fitting source files?

Comment: what you really want?all shortcodes or that specific plugin's shortcode?

Comment: @Anju all shortcodes would be best, but I just want to know whats possible. Would make it much easier if I could just see where I have to look for the code. And I am interested in how wp connects shortcodes with the appropriate files to know which code to execute where without having to look through all the files in the wp directory to find the shortcode or is that whats happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get a list of all registered shortcodes.

```
<?php
    global $shortcode_tags;
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($shortcode_tags); 
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This will unfortunately not give you the source files of these shortcodes but a simple search through your plugins and themes should reveal the location of the shortcode.

Comment: Which command would I use to search through all of my files at once? Until now I had to go through every file, tedious work...

Comment: You could simply use a editor to search in all files, i use Netbeans for development and has a great site search feature.

If you are using Ubuntu command line i suggest browsing to the site folder and using something similar to

`sudo find / -type d -name "SHORTCODE NAME"`

Replace SHORTCODE NAME with the shortcode you are looking for.

Comment: How exactly can I search through all files at the same time in an editor? Thanks for the linux line!

Comment: Once you've setup a site in Netbeans you can simply click on any folder within the site and Ctrl+F, insert the text you are searching for and it returns all files containing the searched text.

https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/FindInProjects/

Comment: ah I see, going to look into netbeans now! Thanks very much for your help! one last question, if you have the time: Why did someone downvote my question/what can I do to improve my questioning here on stackoverlow?

Comment: No problem at all, Netbeans is great IDE, definitely worth looking into. Not to sure about the down vote, perhaps the user could not understand the question. Always stick to these guidelines and you should be fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can print all shortcodes by putting this in a template:

```
<?php

        global $shortcode_tags;

        echo "<pre>"; 

        print_r($shortcode_tags); 

        echo "</pre>";

?>
```

if you need to include in function.php copy the code to function.php

```
function add_shortcodes_metaboxes() {

    add_meta_box('available_shortcodes', 'Available Shortcodes', 'available_shortcodes', 'page', 'side', 'default');

    add_meta_box('available_shortcodes', 'Available Shortcodes', 'available_shortcodes', 'post', 'side', 'default');

}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_shortcodes_metaboxes' );

function available_shortcodes() {

    global $shortcode_tags;

    foreach ($shortcode_tags as $shortcode_tag => $description) {

        echo $shortcode_tag.'<br/>';

    }; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to make sure that I understand your code correctly: what you do is you add a box on the side of each post and page displaying every shortcode tag?